# RabbitMQ: Check queue exists

Tags: rabbitmq

For rabbitMQ it can be checked with channel.queueDeclarePassive if a queue exists or not, throwing an exception if the later is the case. However, also the channel will be terminated then.

How can I check if a queue exists, without that the channel will be terminated?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could redeclare the queue, not passively.

`channel.queueDeclare`

this will either do nothing if the queue already exists, or it will create the queue.

but as for checking if it exists, without recreating it, queueDeclarePassive is your only real option.

Comment: you can send passive redeclares as long as you use the same arguments used when declaring the queue. @user234