# Check wether a queue exists in RabbitMQ with pika library

Tags: python, rabbitmq, fastapi, pika

I have one worker that takes jobs from a Redis Queue.

Each running job will print out its logs to a RabbitMQ channel.
The name of the channel is the JobUUID.

I want to allows client-side to open a websocket that will send all the logs of a specific jobs whenever those are written to the queue (in order to render a CLI like window, similar to what you can see in every CI/CD tools - like github actions, Gitlab CI, Travis and so on).

My problem is that I want to check whenever a client tries to get the logs of a specific job, send to him a not found error if this jobs has no open channel

I found this [RabbitMQ: Check queue exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412092/rabbitmq-check-queue-exists)

But of course this does not suits my use case since I do not want to declare queue but just checking if there is any with this jobUUID as name.

So far my code looks like this

```py
@app.websocket("/{job_id}/logs")
async def get_job_logs(websocket: WebSocket, job_id: str):
    await websocket.accept()
    async def retrieve_message(message: IncomingMessage):
        m = message.body.decode('utf8')
        if m == "END_OF_PIPELINE":
            print("WILL BREAK")
            await websocket.send_text(f"END OF {job_id}")
        if len(m) > 1 :
            await websocket.send_text(json.dumps(m))
    consumer = AsyncConsumer()
    await consumer.connect(job_id, retrieve_message)
    while True:
        await websocket.receive_text()
```

How can I take the JobID that I receive as a parameter and check with it if there is any queue with this name openend. Again I do not want to open a new one if there is no such queue because it is not the role of that WS route to open but only to consume messages.

Btw the `AsyncConsumer` is a class of my own based on pika...it works and well tested..